Existence of everywhere continuous, nowhere differentiable function with finite multiplicity.
Does there exists a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that:
$(1)$ $f$ is continuous everywhere.
$(2)$ $f$ is differentiable nowhere. 
$(3)$ For every $c \in range(f)$, there is only a finite number of points $x_1,...,x_k$ in $[0,1]$ such that, $f(x_i) = c$ for every $i\in \{ 0,..,k \}$.
I saw a related post about A-continuous-nowhere-differentiable-but-invertible-function. Although I am not sure if we can use that result to prove the non-existence of the above function because I don't know any measure theory. I would be grateful if someone showed any old post that dealt with this condition.

Your condition (3) requires there to be no point in the range whose inverse image is an infinite set. It has been known for a long time (over 70 years) that every continuous nowhere differentiable function has the property that "most points" in the range are such that their inverse images have cardinality continuum -- see [12] in this mathoverflow answer. See also Banach's $(T1)$ condition on p. 277 in Theory of the Integral by Saks, and Theorem (6.2) on p. 278.

@DaveL.Renfro Ah ok. Thanks for the reference!
